# Did something on illustrator cc... can't remember what I did! How do I get this result?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I drew lines using the line segment tool. [image]. Then i did ?SOMETHING? by accident and this (the pink) was the result. Anyone able to tell me how to do this again?

I've attached a small section as an example.

Help please!

Answer (score 3):

Group the paths and add a new stroke to the group via the `Appearance Panel`. Then drag the new stroke below the `<contents>` in the panel.

[image]

**Group** the lines... then **add a stroke** to the *Group* via the **Appearance Panel**... then **Move** the stroke **below** the `<contents>` item in the panel

Comment: Thanks for answering! Think I'm missing something though as it didn't work properly. So if i draw a few lines can you take me from there? (sorry I'm new to illustrator but desperately trying!)

Comment: I sort of did... **Group** the lines... then **add a stroke to the Group via the Appearance Panel**... then **Move the stroke** below the `<contents>` item in the panel.